# Windows Server 2022 Routing and FTP port 21

Tags: networking, router, firewall, ftp, windows-server-2022

I use Windows Server 2022 Standard to share Internet connection with Windows 11 computer. I installed DHCP and "Routing and Remote Access" roles to WS2022. In DHCP role I created scope for local addresses (in 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0 subnet) and specified WS2022 address as a default gateway in scope options; I also added Google DNS in scope options. In routing I configured which network adapter is public one and which one is private one.

I connected 2 Windows 11 client to private network adapter of WS2022, and these computers are able to connect to Internet. I opened a lot of websites and used Skype, Viber, AnyDesk, etc... on these computers.

But trouble appeared when I tried to connect to public anonymous FTP server (port 21) from Windows 11 computer. The connection timed out, so I suspected the source of error is firewall. I made tests and found that if I install FTP server to any Windows 11 computer, I can access this local server from another Windows 11 computer, and I also can access any FTP server from Windows Server (even on port 21).

Furthermore, when I disable firewall on Windows Server, I can access FTP servers from Windows 11 computers. So, it looks like firewall blocks outgoing FTP traffic to port 21 from computers that use Windows Server a a router to connect to Internet.

I researched outgoing firewall rules on Windows 2022 server, but I didn't find any outgoing rule related to TCP port 21.

Can anyone advise how does Windows Server 2022 router blocks outgoing connections to port 21 from computers that use this server a a router and how to disable this blocking?

Comment: Are you completely sure that it was the control connection to port 21 and not a data connection which timed out?

Comment: Yes, I am. I pinged port 21 from Windows 11 (client) computers and received timeouts; I also used "passive" mode in FTP clients.

Comment: Have you traced this? What's the response the Server 2022 router is giving?

Comment: In Windows I can not trace specific port via `tracert`, or there is a way to do that? `tracert` can rich FTP server, but it is obvious, because if I use `paping` to access port 80 on some domain, it can access, and if I use `paping` to access 21 port on the same domain, it times out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer at Microsoft support forum finally. In short, by default Windows Server 2022 NAT blocks FTP for any reason, and this fact is not widely advertised or well documented.

There is command line that does the magic and enables FTP clients to connect to remote FTP servers port 21 via Windows Server 2022 NAT:

```
netsh routing ip nat delete ftp
```

Running this command line disables limitations on port 21. You however now become responsible for your own security, so, you have to research possible consequences before doing that.